# Statement Closed: Next Oracle Migration 11g

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ibatis

I am migrating an application from Oracle 10g to Oracle 11g and i am having trouble on a method included on a "OSubjectsqlmapdao" (the application uses ibatis 2).

```
public List retrieveList(String user, String flag)throws Exception
  {

    try{

      logger.info("Retreving List");
      java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;

      Map map = new HashMap();
      map.put("user",user);
      map.put("flag",flag);
      map.put("listRetrieved",null);

      List listRetrieved = new ArrayList();
      queryForObject("DBListRetrieved",map);
      rs = (java.sql.ResultSet)map.get("listRetrieved");    

      logger.info("HAsmap map " +  map.size());

      logger.info("HAsmap map " +  map.isEmpty());


      logger.info("listRetrieved  map " +  map.get("listRetrieved "));


      logger.info("listRetrieved  map getClass" +  map.get("listRetrieved ").getClass());

      OSubject subject = null;
      while (rs.next())
      {       
        subject = new OAsuntos();
        subject.setUser(rs.getString(1));
        subject.setCdode(rs.getString(2));
        subject.setDescrip(rs.getString(3));
        listRetrieved .add(subject );         
      }
      return listRetrieved ;         

    }catch(Exception e){
      logger.error(e.getMessage());
      throw new Exception (e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

The OSubject .xml is defined as following:

```
<parameterMap id="parameterMapRetrieveList" class="map"> 
    <parameter property="listRetrieved" javaType="java.lang.Object" jdbcType="ORACLECURSOR" mode="OUT"/>       
    <parameter property="user"        jdbcType="VARCHAR"          javaType="java.lang.String"   mode="IN"/>
    <parameter property="flag"        jdbcType="VARCHAR"          javaType="java.lang.String"   mode="IN"/>
</parameterMap> 


  <procedure id="DBListRetrieved"  parameterMap="parameterMapRetrieveList">
    { ? = call AS.PCK_LIST.F_RetrieveList(?,?)}
  </procedure>
```

The method worked perfectly in Oracle 10g but it does not work after the migration of the DDBB. Besides, the map list class is according to the log oracle.jdbc.driver when i am not using that driver and i think is not being referenced or even exist on the application.

The Log trace is:

> Retreving List 2014-06-25 14:54:55,098  INFO   OSubjectSqlMapDao
>   (OSubjectSqlMapDao .java:1268) - HAsmap map 3 2014-06-25 14:54:55,099 
>   INFO   OSubjectSqlMapDao (OSubjectSqlMapDao .java:1270) - HAsmap map
>   false 2014-06-25 14:54:55,099  INFO   OSubjectSqlMapDao
>   (OSubjectSqlMapDao .java:1273) - listRetrieved map
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@4efd9ac2 2014-06-25
>   14:54:55,100  INFO   OSubjectSqlMapDao (OSubjectSqlMapDao .java:1276)
>   - listRetrieved map getClassclass oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl 2014-06-25 14:54:55,104  ERROR 
>   OSubjectSqlMapDao (OSubjectSqlMapDao .java:1294) - Closed Statement:
>   next

It would be very helpful if someone could lend me a hand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure how you obtained the `Resultset`, but as there is no `Statement` in sight, it is probably closed, which means the `ResultSet` is closed as well.

Comment: Which ojdbc jar you are using?

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel The Resultset is only an intermediate object to retrieve the list from the map and convert the results into a list of "Subject".

@Lokesh The application is running on a Tomcat 7 with ojdbc5 and ojdbc6 installed on it.

Comment: But what does `queryForObject` do?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel It executes the procedure OSubject.xml . Retrieve the list as an Object and stores it in the map as "listRetrieved"

Comment: That is not enough information. The statement used to produce that `ResultSet` is closed, therefor the `ResultSet` is closed; if you can't fix the problem with that information, you need to show the actual code.

Comment: That is the actual code. The ResultSet is used without a connection. I would like to now how to change the code in order not to use the result set for retrieving the list.